# Mount and Start Docker on Startup

Tags: ubuntu, docker, autostart

I have a local VM running on Ubuntu that, on start, I need to run two commands on (as my user, `andreas`):

```
sudo mount -a 
docker-compose up -d
```

The last command is run in my home directory, and can't be run as root otherwise docker gives me grief. How do I run these two commands automatically when the machine loads, one as root, and one as me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the script as root and use `sudo`'s `-u` option to run the `docker-compose` as your user, and the `-l` option to make sure it's running in a login shell (i.e. the same environment you would have if you logged in[1]).  e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -a
sudo -l -u yourusername docker compose up -d
```

alternatively, use `su`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -a
su -l yourusername docker compose up -d
```

[1] Except for anything to do with X or your GUI desktop environment.